# How can I change a Java FX node's CSS style class at runtime?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a style.css file which contains styles such as:

```
.tab{
    -fx-background-color:rgb(15,63,103);
    ... etc ...
}

.selectedTab{
    -fx-background-color:rgb(52,105,155);
    ... etc ...
}
```

I am trying to change a Button's css at runtime when certain conditions are met.

I know you can set a style by typing the css inline with the:

```
mBtn.setStyle("-fx-background-color:rgb(15,63,103);");
```

Although to me that seems less clean than referencing styles in the .css file.

So I set my buttons CSS initially using:

```
newBtn.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm());
newBtn.getStyleClass().add("tab");
```

But then later, when I try and change it using:

```
mBtn.getStyleClass().removeAll();
mBtn.getStyleClass().add("selectedTab");
```

it doesn't change. Do I need to refresh/redraw the Node after changing it's style?

Also, generally, what is the preferred way to set styles in JavaFX. Is it with setStyle("..."); method or is it by linking it to a stylesheet, or is it a third way I haven't considered.

Thank you for your time :)

Edit: Solved by user [fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991525/fabian) with first comment. The problem was removeAll() is a method that removes all the elements specified as arguments. What I intended to do is actually use the clear() function.

Comment: Look up what `removeAll` does; it's not a different name for the functionality provided by `clear`. In fact in this case it doesn't modify the list at all. In case there are 2 conflicting styles with the same precedence JavaFX just chooses one of them. Using `clear` probably won't yield the desired results though, since this also removes the styles internally used to achieve the normal look of a button. Rounded corners ect. would also vanish, if those style classes are cleared.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, at least not with JavaFX 14. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre]. Note that `getStyleClass().removeAll()` doesn't actually remove anything. That method accepts a vararg (i.e. array) of strings and you're passing an empty array. Your intentions seem to be clear the list, in which case you should use `clear()`. Keep in mind that removing the "button" style class will cause the `Button` to lose all the styles applied by _modena.css_.

Comment: @fabian I thought in CSS that if there's a potential conflict, the style declared later in the style sheet takes precedence.

Comment: You might want to avoid using the class name `tab`, as it's used by `Tab` elements in a `TabPane`; so you might accidentally pick up styles you don't intend to pick up. Use `getStyleClass().remove("tab")` if you're certain you only added the style class once (it will remove the first occurrence); use `getStyleClass().removeAll(Collections.singleton("tab"))` to remove all occurrences of `"tab"`.

Comment: Thank you to the people who have pointed out that "removeAll" doesn't remove anything. I saw it pop up in intellisense and assumed it was "clear".

What is happening is I am adding the style "tab", adding a new style "tabSelected" and then switching back to "tab". Since "tab" is already added and I'm never clearing it, switching back does not work.